# The Number Kidnapper

Tags: mathematics

I was just walking around with my friends Derek, Alice, and Peter, when suddely, WE WERE KIDNAPPED!

We were driven away in a van to a secret hideout, where we met our kidnapper. He calls himself Robert.

"Now listen closely," he said. "I'll let you guys go if you can guess your number. My number is 78."

We agreed, since we really had no other choice.

"All right. Derek, you go first."

Derek seemed scared that the kidnapper knew his name, but he calmed down, and guessed 43.

"That's right! You can go. Alice?"

Alice asked how much time we had. "All the time in the world, my dear."

Alice thought about it for a few minutes, and guessed 30.

"Right again! You can go too. Peter, what's your guess?"

Peter sat there and stammered. "Um, 17?"

"Wrong! You thought your numbers would be in a pattern, but they aren't! There's a code, something the other two must've realized. Guards! Take him to the dungeon."

The guards hauled him off to the dungeon. "His number was 64. Now, ASCIIThenANSI, what's your number?"

I only get one shot before I'm thrown in the dungeon, and you gotta help me!

**What's my number, and why?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your number is

> 131

The numbers are

> The sums of each letter's position in the alphabet
>
>  That is:
>  ROBERT = R + O + B + E + R + T = 18 + 15 + 2 + 5 + 18 + 20 = 78
>  DEREK = D + E + R + E + K = 4 + 5 + 18 + 5 + 11 = 43
>  ALICE = A + L + I + C + E = 1 + 12 + 9 + 3 + 5 = 30
>  PETER = P + E + T + E + R = 16 + 5 + 20 + 5 + 18 = 64

so your number must be

> A + S + C + I + I + T + H + E + N + A + N + S + I =
>  1 + 19 + 3 + 9 + 9 + 20 + 8 + 5 + 14 + 1 + 14 + 19 + 9 = 131

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to just add the character in the name to get the sum. A corresponds to 1, B to 2 and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. Please look at other answers before you post your own. There was already an answer like this one before you posted. Please, if you have the same answer and just want to contribute more, add it as a comment on the previousanswer. Thanks, and welcome to PSE.